# Remove lines from a file that start with a particular string, which includes quotation marks

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to delete around four thousand lines that contain SEU/C0 among around 25,000 lines.
    Find SEU in following line:

```
inpin "SEUC0/example_controller/U0/wrapper_wrappe/genx7.wrapper_controller/pid_reg<3>" A6 ,
```

A bigger section of my test file looks like this:

```
outpin "XDL_DUMMY_INT_R_X27Y147_TIEOFF_X29Y147" HARD1 ,
  inpin "SEUC0/example_controller/U0/wrapper_wrapper/genx7.wrapper_controller/controller_kcpsm3/pc_vector_carry<7>" A6 ,
  inpin "SEUC0/example_controller/U0/wrapper_wrapper/genx7.wrapper_controller/controller_kcpsm3/pc_vector_carry<7>" B6 ,
  inpin "SEUC0/example_controller/U0/wrapper_wrapper/genx7.wrapper_controller/controller_kcpsm3/pc_vector_carry<7>" C6 ,
  inpin "SEUC0/example_controller/U0/wrapper_wrapper/genx7.wrapper_controller/controller_kcpsm3/pc_vector_carry<7>" D6 ,
  pip CLBLM_R_X27Y147 CLBLM_IMUX13 -> CLBLM_L_B6 , 
  pip CLBLM_R_X27Y147 CLBLM_IMUX34 -> CLBLM_L_C6 , 
  pip CLBLM_R_X27Y147 CLBLM_IMUX42 -> CLBLM_L_D6 , 
  pip CLBLM_R_X27Y147 CLBLM_IMUX5 -> CLBLM_L_A6 , 
  pip INT_R_X27Y147 VCC_WIRE -> IMUX13 , 
  pip INT_R_X27Y147 VCC_WIRE -> IMUX34 , 
  pip INT_R_X27Y147 VCC_WIRE -> IMUX42 , 
  pip INT_R_X27Y147 VCC_WIRE -> IMUX5 ,
```

This is the solution I tried:

```
f = open("test.xdl","r+")
d = f.readlines()
f.seek(0)
for i in d:
    if i != "SEU":  # want to remove the SEU string
        f.write(i)
f.truncate()
f.close()
```

If I do this:

```
for i in d:
    if i=='inpin "SEUC0/':
        f.write(i)
f.truncate()
f.close()
```

The output file is empty.

When I try

```
i!="inpin SEUC0/
```

it didn't work because it's a long string, and if I write

```
"inpin "SEUC0/""
```

Python gives an error.

Is there anyway that I can remove all these lines which contain SEUC0?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code almost works, except for the way you're quoting the string and doing the comparison. How about this?

```
f = open("test.xdl","r+")
d = f.readlines()
f.seek(0)
for i in d:
    if not i.strip().startswith('inpin "SEUC0/'):
        f.write(i)
f.truncate()
f.close()
```

Note that this uses single quotes around the search string, so that the string can include a double-quote. It also uses `.strip()` to remove the leading spaces and then uses `.startswith()` to check whether the line starts with the right substring. When you use `==` or `!=`, they check whether the strings are exactly the same. But you only want to check whether the line starts with a particular string.

Comment: It didn't work give me the same output . Without transaction of the line..

Comment: And if i do :  for i in d:
    if i=='inpin "SEUC0/':
        f.write(i)
f.truncate()
f.close() it delete all the file

Comment: Do all the lines in your file start with two spaces ("  inpin..." instead of "inpin...")? If so, change `'inpin "SEUC0/'` to `'  inpin "SEUC0/'` in the code above. Or you could try `'inpin "SEUC0/' in i` instead of `i.startswith('inpin "SEUC0/')`.

Comment: I added `.strip()` which will remove leading spaces from the line. This should work whether or not there are spaces at the start of the line.